# Load an (updating) point layer from Access: Problems with pointslayerfromtable algorithm

Tags: qgis, ms-access

I'm a python dummy user and in general a QGIS dummy user. I'm using 32 bit QGIS 2.14.1 Essen version.

Referred to the post [How to load an (updating) point layer from Access?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151709/how-to-load-an-updating-point-layer-from-access/190308?noredirect=1#comment287220_190308) ,i try underdark solution but it doesn't work with an access mdb. I don't know what underdark means when write "Check the Processing | Log to see the syntax for Access" because in QGIS Processing Log menu doesn't suggest syntax for Access.Here the code where i replace sensitive information with opportune tag:

```
import processing 

def openProject(): 
    pts=processing.runalg("qgis:pointslayerfromtable","ODBC:<UserDSNname>|layername=<tablename>|subset="and"fieldX"and"= 'ValueX'","X","Y","EPSG:32633", None) 
    processing.load(pts['OUTPUT'])
```

Obviously it doesn't work :-(. I tried to manually compile the code above (excluding "def openProject():") in python console in order to understand which is the problem. Following the output:

```
Console Python 
Usa iface per accedere all'interfaccia API QGIS oppure digita help(iface)per le informazioni 
import processing 
pts=processing.runalg("qgis:pointslayerfromtable","ODBC:  <UserDSNname>|layername=<tablename>|subset="and"fieldX"and"= 'ValueX'","X","Y","EPSG:32633", None) 
Error: Wrong parameter value: = 'ValueX'
```

excluding the fieldX filter condition, the result doesn't change:

```
pts=processing.runalg("qgis:pointslayerfromtable","ODBC:<UserDSNname>|layername=<tablename>","X","Y","EPSG:32633", None) 
Error: Wrong parameter value: ODBC:<UserDSNname>|layername=<tablename></i>
```

The same error appears if i change the USERDSNname with mdb pathfile:

```
Console Python 
Usa iface per accedere all'interfaccia API QGIS oppure digita help(iface) per le informazioni 
import processing 
pts=processing.runalg("qgis:pointslayerfromtable","<pathfolder>\<DBname>.mdb|layername=<tablename>|subset="and"fieldX"and"= 'ValueX'","X","Y","EPSG:32633", None) 
Error: Wrong parameter value: = 'ValueX' 
pts=processing.runalg("qgis:pointslayerfromtable","<pathfolder>\<DBname>.mdb|layername=<tablename>","X","Y","EPSG:32633", None) 
Error: Wrong parameter value: <pathfolder>\<DBname>.mdb|layername=<tablename>
```

I understand that ODBC connection or db access pathfile doesn't work properly...Can you help me? In the web i don't find any information that can help me. Another observation: applying the command with a csv file instead of mdb file, as tried by underdark in the referred post, all works well.

Comment: Since I'm a new user, i wonder if it's possible to tag users of the referred question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151709/how-to-load-an-updating-point-layer-from-access because i think that they can easily solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: I am not certain of this, but if you are using the 64 bit version of QGIS, you will need 64 bit drivers to interface to an Access MDB file.
This has been an issue in the past with other software packages, and Microsoft finally gave into the pressure to build the 64 bit drivers for what was called "Jet" in 32 bit.

Comment: Hi jbgramm i'm using 32 bit version of QGIS and the manual ms access table ODBC connection import works well in QGIS.